# oracle Golden gate for big data kafka adapter grouping data to kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, grouping, adapter, oracle-golden-gate

Source: Oracle Database
Target: kafka

Moving data from source to target by oracle golden adapter for big data. Problem is data is moving fine but  when am inserting 5 records its going as one file in topic.

I want to group it. If am making 5 insert i need five separate entries in topic(kafka)

kafka handler, version gg for big data 12.3.1

Am inserting five records in source  and in khafka am getting  all inserts  like below

```
{"table":"MYSCHEMATOPIC.ELASTIC_TEST","op_type":"I","op_ts":"2017-10-24 08:52:01.000000","current_ts":"2017-10-24T12:52:04.960000","pos":"00000000030000001263","after":{"TEST_ID":2,"TEST_NAME":"Francis","TEST_NAME_AR":"Francis"}}
{"table":"MYSCHEMATOPIC.ELASTIC_TEST","op_type":"I","op_ts":"2017-10-24 08:52:01.000000","current_ts":"2017-10-24T12:52:04.961000","pos":"00000000030000001437","after":{"TEST_ID":3,"TEST_NAME":"Ashfak","TEST_NAME_AR":"Ashfak"}}
{"table":"MYSCHEMATOPIC.ELASTIC_TEST","op_type":"U","op_ts":"2017-10-24 08:55:04.000000","current_ts":"2017-10-24T12:55:07.252000","pos":"00000000030000001734","before":{"TEST_ID":null,"TEST_NAME":"Francis"},"after":{"TEST_ID":null,"TEST_NAME":"updatefrancis"}}
{"table":"MYSCHEMATOPIC.ELASTIC_TEST","op_type":"D","op_ts":"2017-10-24 08:56:11.000000","current_ts":"2017-10-24T12:56:14.365000","pos":"00000000030000001865","before":{"TEST_ID":2}}
{"table":"MYSCHEMATOPIC.ELASTIC_TEST","op_type":"U","op_ts":"2017-10-24 08:57:43.000000","current_ts":"2017-10-24T12:57:45.817000","pos":"00000000030000002152","before":{"TEST_ID":3},"after":{"TEST_ID":4}}
```

Comment: Which handler are you using - Kafka, or Kafka Connect? Which version of GoldenGate? How are you determining it is "5 records as one file"?

Comment: kafka handler, version gg for big data 12.3.1, Am inserting five records in source  and in khafka am getting  all inserts  like above

Comment: Am inserting 1 million record in my source as initial load. In target file going as single record to kafka. How to avoid this?

Comment: Can you show the command you're running to get the output shown? That to me looks like five separate messages in Kafka, which is what I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [Kafka Connect Handler](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/bd123110/gg-bd/GADBD/using-kafka-connect-handler.htm), since it then registers the data's schema with the Confluent Schema Registry, making it much easier to stream onwards to targets such as Elasticsearch (using Kafka Connect).

In Kafka each record from Oracle will be one Kafka message.

Answer (score 0):

Made below in .props  file

gg.handler.kafkahandler.mode=op.

And it worked!!